# there is no application running at 127.0.0.1 -- unable to find dyk.controller.socket.timout keyword in yourkit folder?

Tags: yourkit

> Please try to increase socket timeouts of the profiler profiler UI by specifying `-Dyk.controller.connect.timeout.ms=` (default is `5000` ms) and `-Dyk.controller.read.timeout.ms=` (default is `30000` ms) in `/.yjp/ui.ini`
>
> For example, set
>
> `-Dyk.controller.connect.timeout.ms=60000 -Dyk.controller.read.timeout.ms=60000`

I don't have this `dyk.controller` in my `yourkit` folder.
Where is the file in which to increase the socket timeout?

Answer (score 0):

-Dyk.controller.* is a JVM properties which should be specified in $USER_HOME/.yjp/ui.ini file